# Ajax log in form submit doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

This form allow to log in for wrong details.But validations work. Can you please tell me where is the issue? Is this format correct for send multiple form data?
login_process.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("connnection.php"); 

$con=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

}

  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email1']);
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password1']);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' AND passwordR='$password' AND status='1' ";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$query)or die(mysqli_error($con));
  $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  if( $num_row ==1 )
         {
   $_SESSION['user_name']=$email;
   echo "Form Submitted Succesfully";


  }


 mysqli_close($con);  ?>
```

Here is my Ajax code. Im not sure whether data is sent correctly to the php file

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#login").click(function(){

var email = $("#username").val();
var password = $("#password").val();

// Returns successful data submission message when the entered INFORMATION is stored in database.
var dataString = '&email1='+ email + '&password1='+ password ;
if(email==''||password=='')
{
$(".error-messages").text("You must fill each field").show();
}
else
{
// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "login_process.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(result){
location.href="member_area.php";
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
```

Comment: "AND passwordR='$password' " is passwordR purpose or the error?

Comment: Why are you doing a data string if you are doing `post`? Why not serialize your form?

Comment: @michael it is the correct one. No error there

Comment: @Rasclatt I'm new to ajax. Don't know how to do that. Can you refer some resources to learn it?

Comment: What is the name of your form (`id="formname"`)?

Comment: Also, I presume you are trying to redirect the user if their USER/PASS is validated?

Comment: Its "login_form" . Yes to the member area. If not back to login page(login.html).

Comment: I just tested my answer (if you copy every part as is) it will work as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the first portion. This will validate your form and submit to the `<div id="response"></div>"`. You also have to change your form tag to `<form method="post" name="login_form" id="login_form">` (add the `id` not just `name`). Also I have used jQuery form validation to validate your form:

```
<!-- This line needs to include the id, not just name attribute -->
<form method="post" name="login_form" id="login_form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username/email" name="email" id="username">
    <p style="color:red;" id="errors1"></p>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" id="password">
    <p style="color:red;" id="errors2"></p>
    <a href="reset_password.php" class="forgot">forgot password?</a>
    <input type="submit" id="login" name="submit" value="Sign In" />
</form>

<!-- This is where instructions load into from the ajax. it is required for this to work -->
<div id="response"></div>

<!-- required for jQuery, you likely have these already -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- required for jQuery form validation to work -->
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            // Validate the form->see rules below
            $("#login_form").validate({
                // On success of the form validation
                // submit AJAX
                submitHandler: function() {
                    // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "login_process.php",
                            data: $("#login_form").serialize(),
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(data){
                                    $("#response").html(data);
                                }
                        });
                    return false;
                },
            // See jQuery validate() for more options for rules
            rules: {
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                password: {
                    required: true//,
                    //minlength: 8
                }
            },
            messages: {
                email: {
                    required: "Username Required",
                    email: "Invalid Email"
                },
                password: {
                    required: "Password Required",
                    minlength: "8 Character Minimum"
                }
            }
        });
    });                 
</script>
```

**login_process.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("connnection.php"); 

$con    =   mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

}

    $email      =   mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $password   =   mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $query      =   "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' AND passwordR='$password' AND status='1' ";
    $result     =   mysqli_query($con,$query)or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $num_row    =   mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $row        =   mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if( $num_row ==1 ) {
            $_SESSION['user_name']  =   $email; ?>
    <script>
    // This would redirect on load
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        window.location =   'member_area.php';
    });
    </script>
            <?php
        }
    else { ?>
    <h1>Wrong Username/Password</h1>
    <?php }


 mysqli_close($con);  ?>
```

**EDIT:** This line had `html` spelled wrong. Should be `$("#response").html(data);` not `$("#response").hmtl(data);`

Comment: Did you add the jquery validation library link?

Comment: Also the validation library link has to come after the regular jquery library links. If your form is not validating then you likely have the link missing or not placed in the correct spot

Comment: Here is it working: [Demo](http://www.xolifestyleworldwide.com/client_assets/workboard.php)

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked !. In login_process.php file name attribute values(email1 to email and password1 to password) need to change as in html form. Because there are no intermediate variables.  Thanks again.

Comment: I will edit my answer to fix that. I never even looked at the sql stuff but best to edit the answer so it's totally correct. If it's good, just mark it correct so no one else comes to this question to try and solve it when it's already been solved.